# How to change the dictionary of the list with condition

Tags: python

How do I remove information from one list to another if the condition is true?

Example: at the end of the code I must validate which contacts are 18 years old or more and take them out of the original list and put them in a new one, also for those under 18 years old.

However, when I use extend, it does not meet the condition and transfers the entire list to both conditions

```
informations = []

for i in range(3):
  name = str(input('Contact name? '))
  if name == '':
    print('Programa encerrado...')
    break
  age = int(input('Age of contact? '))
  cellphone = int(input('What is your phone number? '))
  
  informations.append({'name': name,'age':age,'cellphone':cellphone})
  informations.sort(key=lambda contact: contact['name'])

print('')
print('Dictionary {}'.format(informations))
print('')

aboveOf18, belowOf18 = [], []
    
for contact in informations:
    if contact['age'] > 18:
        aboveOf18.extend(informations)
    elif contact['age'] < 18:
        belowOf18.extend(informations)
        
print('Dictionary > 18: {}'.format(aboveOf18))
print('')
print('Dictionary < 18: {}'.format(belowOf18))
```

Help me please

Comment: first suggestion is using `f strings` (not that it solves the problem just a suggestion)

Comment: so the issue is that when a condition is met it just transfers the whole dictionary because that is how You haves specified it, comment below explains this better

Comment: Think carefully about your logic. By doing `for contact in informations:`, the idea is to look at *one `contact` at a time*, and decide where to put it, right? So, let's say you have decided to put it into `aboveOf18`. What should that code look like? (Hint: what is the name of the thing you are putting in? Will it be a list, or a single item?)

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that causes the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it really was a failure of the basic logic, I tried all the ways except this haha, thank you very much

Comment: @Matiiss thanks for your suggestion

Comment: never use variables names like `aboveOf18` but `above_18` instead. python variables/functions/methods should use snake_case, and classes use CapitalCase, but never use camelCase (like in Java, Groovy, C#...)

Comment: @DevLounge I didn't know, I was using the camelCase pattern that I learned when I was viewing javascript, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to formally fix your code as well - it looks like you need to replace `extend(informations)` with `append(contact)` if you'd like to create two new lists of dictionaries based on condition (and not extend it with everything three times).

```
for contact in informations:
    if contact['age'] >= 18:
        aboveOf18.append(contact)
    else:
        belowOf18.append(contact)
```

Other guys answering/commenting make a really good point/suggestions by the way.

Comment: my God, it was so basic, now it makes sense to comment above the @Karl, thank you so much for giving me the vision of the error

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you consider something along the lines of:

```
aboveOf18 = [x for x in informations if x['age'] >= 18]
```

From this, you should be able to figure out how to do the below.

Comment: i wonder how the OP will comprehend this "complex" list compression, if he could not handle a simple logical flaw (not to blame him, we all sometimes make mistakes). other than that OP should definitely learn this. anyhow I did not mean to be rude or anything (just in case)

Comment: Give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, feed him fro a lifetime. I'd rather give part of it and make sure they can understand what's happening.

Comment: @user3832673
I read it several times, researched it and really didn’t understand the way it was presented above, my level of knowledge is very initial

Comment: @MarcosPrado You can read the first part `aboveOf18 = [x for x in informations ...]` like this: `aboveOf18` is a list of all items (here named `x`) from the original list `informations`...

Comment: @MarcosPrado ... and continue with the second part `... if x['age'] >= 18]` like this: [the items] for which the condition `x['age'] >= 18` is valid.

Comment: @lenka_cizkova thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

**This is NOT answer**

These days, I completely stopped using dictionaries to store arbitrary data.
Instead there is dataclasses which make code much cleaner

**Example:**

```
contact = {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 30, 'cellphone': '555-12345'}
age = contact['age']
contact['name'] = 'new name'
```

Can instead be:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Contact:

    name: str
    age: int
    cellphone: str

contact = Contact(name='John Doe', age=30, cellphone='555-12345')
age = contact.age
contact.name = 'New Name'
```

Which one is cleaner and more pleasant visualy ?

Comment: class part definitely looks better, but what if You need to store somewhat large amounts of data? it then will not be that easy since You would have to hardcode that data, wouldn't You?

Comment: There’s dataclass_json extension which provides .from_dict or .from_json. I suppose that large data would be somehow structured so it could be super easy to convert.....

Comment: @DevLounge thanks for the suggestion, but for the resolution of the study, my teacher requested the use of dictionary and list. But it's good to learn about the classes too haha

Comment: sure, no issue, enjoy learning Python, it's great!